# ios5 core data or pref list

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, nsfilemanager

q) what is the best method of storing persons complete details i.e.

steve > details contain :name address,dob, other details etc..
john > details contain :name address,dob, other details etc..

and many more records max would be around 200 tops.

now i want to display these individually and with the option to add them what is the suggested way?

i had a look at core data,userdefaults and NSFileManager but not sure what would be best way to implement such nested texts for save and load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to search or query them I would always recommend going with core data from the get go.
You'll only end up wishing you add gone down that route in a few months and then would have to factor in a migration.
For core data I use https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord for new projects, it does most of the heavy lifting for you.

For a recent app I used NSUserDefaults. Basically keeping all my 'person' objects as NSDictionaries in an NSArray. This suited the app as the data was low, c100 records in use max.
I could just as easily have used a save to disk method, but as I did't have any other use for saving small amounts of preference data, it was just a convenience.
(remember, accessing NSUserDefaults brings back all its contents, not just the particular object you are interested in).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thx for the intresting project magicalrecords i'm thinking the data i.e. each user will be saved as individual file i.e.

steve > details contain :name address,dob, other details etc.. 

john > details contain :name address,dob, other details etc..


user will pick and load these files, noting this is that still best option, as this is my first ios app coming from android bit confused thats all :)  - in android used sqlite but initial used shared preference list.

does this change your answer?

Comment: make a quick tableview app with a bunch of dummy data stored in an array. I think storing to disk or nsuserdefaults will be easier initially whilst you get a feel for how the user will use the data.

Comment: if similiar view to the address book, then a saved array and iterating through its contents via a search bar is the easiest solution.